# collection view paging cell off center

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I enabled paging via interface builder and when I scroll (I am using horizontal scrolling) it doesn't center the collection cell, instead as I progress it starts to end half in the screen.

I only have one giant cell displayed at a time.

Any suggestions as to how I can tell the page to center the cell on the screen?

Thanks

Comment: ok, layout is flow... I removed line spacing, but it didn't fully fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make small change on collectionView size and flowLayout:

If you need section Insets: set left = right (if not set All = 0)

MinimumLineSpacing always = 0;

CollectionViewSize = CellSize and collectionView.center = self.view.center.

Sample: https://github.com/lequysang/github_zip/blob/master/CollectionViewImagesCenterCell.zip

Comment: What do you mean by added to? Just change size in flowLayout in IB or storyBoard.